# Javascript Not Rendering Style in HTML (Dropbox)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set up collapsible FAQs on my [webpage](http://graduatemediaservices.com/expert-guidance), and got the functionality to work (yay!), but had issues with the style interfering with other styles on the page (see the grey header and About Us boxes).

Since I don't want to mess up the style for the rest of the site, I am setting up an iframe to get around the interference. I've copied my code to an HTML file, uploaded on Dropbox [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/744ehssrysv0i64/ExpertFAQ.html?dl=0), but the script/style does not seem to be working.

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing? Thank you!

(Edit for code)

What I am using at the bottom of my website (the working collapsible FAQs) is simply:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" /><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>What is a typical call like?</h4>
    <p>Before our call, we will decide on a topic for the call and set a working agenda. We will try to stay on topic during the call, but can cover anything else that would be beneficial to you during our session. At the end of the call, we can decide if a follow up call would be beneficial to discuss results or to cover a related topic.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>What if I have a detailed technical question?</h4>
    <p>Our team has a wide knowledge base of online advertising platforms and strategies. That said, there may be some topics that are highly specialized that would require some research. We will try to get you an answer during our call or follow up if we are unable to help immediately. If we feel that we would be unable to provide you with sufficient value on our call, we will let you know before it's scheduled so we don't take up your time.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Are there any contracts?</h4>
    <p>Before we talk, we'll send over our general policies and will require acknowledgement of them. However, our calls will be scheduled as needed and you are not bound to schedule any additional calls (unless you want to).</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>What if I want to set up recurring calls?</h4>
    <p>That's great! We think you'll get the best results from continuing discussions to check performance, get further recommendations, and discuss new marketing ideas. We will set up a recurring schedule (often bi-weekly) so you can plan around our calls.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>What if I decide that I need more help?</h4>
    <p>We can walk you through whatever you're working on, or we can do it for you under one of our service plans. We'll recommend a plan that will fit your needs and can get you set up as soon as possible.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>How do I pay? What payment methods are accepted?</h4>
    <p>After our call, we'll send you a follow-up email with a summary of our discussion and an invoice. If you decided to schedule recurring calls, the invoice will include a retainer for any additional calls that month. We want to minimize the administrative burden on you and strive to make the process as seamless as possible. From your invoice, you'll be able to make an online payment using: Visa, MasterCard, American Express, JCB, Discover, and Diners Club cards.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I have included in my HTML file upload to Dropbox is the same, but with "html" and other tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>FAQs</h1>
  </div>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>What is a typical call like?</h4>
    <p>Before our call, we will decide on a topic for the call and set a working agenda. We will try to stay on topic during the call, but can cover anything else that would be beneficial to you during our session. At the end of the call, we can decide if a follow up call would be beneficial to discuss results or to cover a related topic.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>What if I have a detailed technical question?</h4>
    <p>Our team has a wide knowledge base of online advertising platforms and strategies. That said, there may be some topics that are highly specialized that would require some research. We will try to get you an answer during our call or follow up if we are unable to help immediately. If we feel that we would be unable to provide you with sufficient value on our call, we will let you know before it's scheduled so we don't take up your time.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Are there any contracts?</h4>
    <p>Before we talk, we'll send over our general policies and will require acknowledgement of them. However, our calls will be scheduled as needed and you are not bound to schedule any additional calls (unless you want to).</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>What if I want to set up recurring calls?</h4>
    <p>That's great! We think you'll get the best results from continuing discussions to check performance, get further recommendations, and discuss new marketing ideas. We will set up a recurring schedule (often bi-weekly) so you can plan around our calls.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>What if I decide that I need more help?</h4>
    <p>We can walk you through whatever you're working on, or we can do it for you under one of our service plans. We'll recommend a plan that will fit your needs and can get you set up as soon as possible.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>How do I pay? What payment methods are accepted?</h4>
    <p>After our call, we'll send you a follow-up email with a summary of our discussion and an invoice. If you decided to schedule recurring calls, the invoice will include a retainer for any additional calls that month. We want to minimize the administrative burden on you and strive to make the process as seamless as possible. From your invoice, you'll be able to make an online payment using: Visa, MasterCard, American Express, JCB, Discover, and Diners Club cards.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're using an iframe, the styles on the iframe's source page will be preserved. You'd have to copy your styles and include them in your dropbox page, too.

Comment: Please post your code here as well.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for the quick responses! I updated the post to include the code that's working on my site, and the code that is not formatting/styling properly through my HTML file. I should be able to find styling on my page, but why would it work (collapse) in the original code and not on the HTML file? I didn't add anything except the HTML, Body, etc. tags. Is the working code picking up the styling from my page maybe?

Comment: Please open your developer tools (press F12) and take a look at the console log. You should see some errors which will explain why it's not working.

Comment: Yes! That fixed it! I was pulling http:// instead of https://. Thank you all!! :)